# Constrained block placement puzzle

Tags: computer-science, puzzle

I'm trying to design a mathematical model for an algorithm I need for my program.

#### The problem

I have a 3d grid in which I have a shape $S$ and I need to fill this shape with block types $B$ in a way that every block type $b \in B$ satisfy its own 6 neighbor constraints. In other words, for every $b$, for each of the 6 directions $D$, I have a list of block types that are allowed to be placed nearby and I need to arrange these block types in order to fill the shape.

#### Initial steps

I've found a paper that describes a similar problem (*The Jigsaw Puzzle*) and propose a mathematical model for it: https://shaharkov.github.io/projects/GlobalPuzzles.pdf.

My first guess is: I need for every position of $S$ to know which $b$ to associate so the ideal thing would be to have a system of $N$ equations ($N = \#S$), with $N$ variables $(b_{p_0}, ..., b_{p_{n-1}})$ with $b_{p_0}$ being the block type to set for position 0.

However what resulted to be hard is writing the system itself:

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\sum_{d=1}^{6}r_d(b_{p_0}, b_{rel(p_0, d)})) = 6 & p_0 = (0, 0, 0)\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
\sum_{d=1}^{6}r_d(b_{p_{n-1}}, b_{rel(p_{n-1}, d)})) = 6 & p_{n-1} = (p_{{n-1}_x}, p_{{n-1}_y}, p_{{n-1}_z})\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

I imagined to have a $r_d$ function (with $d$ being one of the 6 directions: front, back, left, right, top, bottom), that given two block types - one at position $p$ and the other at the neighbor position subject to $d$ - returns $\{0, 1\}$, $0$ if the two blocks doesn't match, $1$ if the two blocks match.

However it turned out it's really hard to think how to implement $r_d$: for a block type at a certain position $b_p$ I would need to *mathematically encode* that $b_{rel(p, d)}$ must be in the list of allowed blocks of $b_p$ for direction $d$ and therefore the function can return $1$, otherwise $0$.

Can anyone help me with this?